# Turn on Desktop Session Host without domain involvement

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, windows

I am trying to retrofit an existing VM that runs Windows Server 2008 R2 to allow some application testing.

What I need is to support Aero over Remote Desktop.  I have [read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/06/23/aero-glass-remoting-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) that to do that I need the Desktop Session Host (RDSH) role.

But the tutorials I have seen for that involve active directory and the domain controller.  Interaction with either of those requires paperwork and a lot of wait time at my company.

**Is there some way I can turn this one without needing elevated rights to either of those?**

(I have basic "ASK" rights for Active Directory and the VM is part of the domain already.)

Comment: Are you an administrator on that server?  The challenging thing is that RDSH requires terminal server CALs.  TSCALs generally need to be implemented domain-wide.

Comment: @Zoredache - I am an Admin on that server.  (I am a software developer and it is a Dev Only Server.)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you need to enable the RD Session Host role.  I was able to enable Aero by just installing the [Desktop Experience](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772567.aspx) features on my server.  That being said, it made things VERY slow over remote connections on our internet connection.

Comment: How are you defining remote connections here?  Within our office, connecting from Windows 7 Clients the performance seems to be fine.  Even at my home over my broadband connection it isn't that bad.

Comment: Desktop Experience below 10mbit is not supported bprioer to 2012. RemoteFX WAN is needed (2012, graphics Card) for that. This is a documentated Limitation - RemoteFX is a "local area onily" tech Prior to 2012.

Comment: @Zoredache Sorry, updated the answer to clarify as over the internet connection.

Comment: @TomTom I don't know about that mbps limitation, we only had a 20 down, 10 up that if it was lucky achieved 18 down and 8 up. (FiOS) Aero worked and displayed, the issue was simply the extra data that had to be rendered and then shipped to the client. It didn't *prevent* us from turning it on though.

Comment: Well, specs are clear. in 2012 that is removed - it is usable fully over internet, with very good scaling. YOu have not seen proper rremote desktop until you experienced the changes they did - HUGH.

Comment: I turned on Desktop Experience and I still don't get the Aero UI in my Remote Desktop sessions.

Comment: Did you select and set a theme that then uses Aero?